# Board replacement on cantilever room

Tags: replacement, rot

I have a cantilevered room and on the exterior of the house the board which seems to be like particle board AFAIK and is is rotting off the underside. There's no leaks as far as I can tell and the wood under the board seems fine, no rot no damage. I'm in the northeast so I imagine snow and humid weather is the culprit here .

There are cellulose plugs going into the actual wood under the cantilever so I believe all I need to do is replace the board and seal it because the actual insulation is still in place.

My question is what kind of board should I use to replace it and how should I do it? I believe it's particle board but I'm no expert and I believe whoever did it before just used nails and no sealant.

What would be the best replacement material to replace the board and what would be the best way to secure and seal it?

I'm pretty much a beginner in terms of DIY stuff so if anyone could offer a simple explanation I would appreciate it! Pictures below.
https://imgur.com/a/wLcRgvd

Comment: What is the insulation and vapor barrier situation under there?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing whether you need to deal with insulation or air barrier, I'd suggest that this is just like any other soffit situation, such as under your roof overhang. Some ideas:

- Aluminum or vinyl soffit
- Treated plywood
- Vinyl planking